# Does stackexchange currently have a forum or otherwise where posts asking for general advice are welcome?

Tags: discussion

Does stackexchange currently have a forum or otherwise where posts such as this would be welcome?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195731/tactics-devices-to-achieve-huge-fast-and-low-latency-dac-output-from-a-pc-contr?noredirect=1#comment407358_195731

I've done a bit of reading re. the 'intention' of how the sites work, some of it critical, some defensive, some bone-headed bureaucratic stupidity and some very precise and positive insight with very real clarity of purpose.*

It is *also* my opinion that a stack-site on topic-A will generally have the best online presence of topic-A experts. I note that some of the comments in that question hint at exactly the kind of thing I'd love to hear/learn about - I know the knowledge is out there in the users! - but discussion thwarted...

Am I missing something?

Could just be a local hiccup for me only - but I feel like asking a question on stackexchange site is like running through a shooting range.

(in part intended to solve the issue of messy forum-models/interfaces of the past ... that I suspect I might be directed to with my query as it stands)

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain why this post was down-voted?

Comment: Downvote on meta has a different meaning.  It means disagreement.  It doesn't mean that the post is sub-standard in some way.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, good to know :)   ...ok, so can the disagreer please explain why they disagreed with this post?  (*can* you actually disagree with any of it?)

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree with your opinion or proposal.  That doesn't mean you are a moron, need a bath, and that it implies certain things about your heritage, like it does on the main site.  Another reason for the downvote is this pops up periodically, particularly from newbies, and it gets tiring to have to waste time to dispense with it each time.  Frankly, those that haven't been here long enough (like below a few 100 rep at least), shouldn't have rights to opinions on how the site is run.  Learn it before barging in here proclaiming it should be changed.  You're not ready yet.

Answer (score 4):

The customs here are what they need to be so that this can continue to be the top EE site.  You said yourself, this place has the best presence of experts, and when you really want to know something, you come here.

This does not occur by accident.  It is a good place because we keep it clean.  That keeps the experts here that you seek information from.  Other sites are so overloaded with drivel that experts find it too much of a hassle, which means they leave, which ensures only more drivel.

To get the site *you* want, you first have to give the experts the site *they* want.

This comes with some restrictions, both on content that would irritate the experts, and on content that just doesn't work with the Q+A format of this site.  This is not a "forum", it's a Q+A site, which takes some getting used in the beginning, and ultimately requires a different mindset.

From experience, certain types of questions have been found not to work here.  This includes open-ended discussions, solicitations of opinions, and anything that doesn't have a answer that can be judged right or wrong.  What you are asking for falls into these catagories.

If you don't like that, remember that these restrictions make the content you are getting possible.  There is no way to have everything.  Appreciate what you do have here, which is still way better than all the other sites that are either overrun with spam, or with the great unwashed masses babbling drivel to each other.  No thanks.

Comment: I just wrote a rather snarky response to your comment above ( I felt it deserved it), but here in this answer you're being quite reasonable and I agree with it... Puzzling ...  Anyways, I was asking a question, I hear the answer is 'no' - *heard*

Comment: p.s. what metric do you use when you say that EE is the top site?

Comment: @Lam: I was echoing what you said about it being the best place to get EE information.  As for snarky comments, bring it on.  They're usually good for a few laughs, though the mods might not appreciate them as much.

Comment: @LamarLatrell - the metric I use is that I'm here and I'm on no other EE site (I wonder how many upvotes this comment will get for me being such a gobshi*e)

Comment: @OlinLathrop - heh heh :) - Well, you're in luck, I cut it out of the comment and it was still in the clipboard:  **" How about you learn *my* opinion before deciding it needs to be changed? Aside from that, I get the feeling that people tell you certain things quite often, so maybe I'll refrain and save the typing. night night sweety."**

Comment: OK so who said "night night sweety" - I should pop around more often! I'm missing all the toilet talk it seems.

Answer (score 3):

The customs on EE.SE are Spartan.

If you have a broad and unclear question like that, it helps to incubate it on your own first.  Do some systems engineering.  Do some preliminary research.

About the only place within SE where you can try your luck with stream of consciousness questions are SE chats.  Of course, there are people with sharp knives in the chats too.

Comment: Research leads to 1. Wikipedia: ('broad and unclear' itself/errors/jargon) - 2. Vendor websites: (terrible interfaces/vague/waaay too much info/more jargon/sell-sell-sell/lies) or 3. hobby style forums (half-baked ideas/'noobs'/noise) or 4. **stackexchange sites**: which are, for the most part *informative* :)  P.S. Do you perceive my post to be 'stream of consciousness' ?

Comment: ...should also add that university courses sometimes throw up content online too - and that can be helpful, but it's hit and miss

Comment: I would have upvoted except for the first sentence, although I didn't downvote either.